# Neo4j Cypher and index number

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example I have a following query:

```
MATCH (p:Product) ORDER by p.createDate DESC RETURN p
```

and I know the `id` of the some product, let's say `p.id = 10`.

Is it possible with Cypher query to get an index number of this product in the query result? If so, could you please show an example.

For example this query returns the following products with the ids:

```
1, 4, 45, 32, 67, 10, 95, 2
```

So the index number for product with `id = 10` is `6`

Comment: The index of 10 is actually 5, using conventional 0-origin indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (p:Product)
WITH p ORDER by p.createDate DESC
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps
RETURN
  ps,
  REDUCE(ix = -1, i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1) | CASE ps[i].id WHEN 10 THEN i ELSE ix END) AS ix;
```

This should return the sorted collection of `Products` and the (0-origin) index of the (last) one with an `id` of 10 (or -1 if it is not found).

Comment: Thank you very much ! One additional question - is it a heavy operation from a performance point of view on a big collections.. let's say 5000-10000 elements ?

Comment: `REDUCE` has `O(N)` complexity, so it would not be "light". But I don't think you can improve on `O(N)`. Cypher does not support aborting `REDUCE` early, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There's no inherent index here, so you'll need to add it into your query manually, and you'll need to use collections to do this.

```
MATCH (target:Product {id:10}) // should be fast with an index
MATCH (p:Product) 
WITH p
ORDER by p.createDate DESC 
WITH collect(p) as products
UNWIND range(0, size(products) - 1) as index
WITH index, products[index] as product
WHERE product = target
RETURN index, product
```

Comment: Sorry, but where at this query to place a condition for Id = 10 ?

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted the question, I thought this was asking for returning indexes along with all rows. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to APOC Procedures, you can also take advantage of some collection functions to get what you want:

```
MATCH (target:Product {id:10}) // should be fast with an index
MATCH (p:Product) 
WITH p
ORDER by p.createDate DESC 
WITH collect(p) as products
RETURN target, apoc.coll.indexOf(products, target) as index
```